# Expose Eureka Server port to outside in Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm implementing a Helm chart which deploys a simple Eureka server with one work node and one control plane:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/tree/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart

I deploy this helm chart on native kubernetes installation.
How I can expose port 8761 to be visible to outside network so that I can open it in my browser by running `http://....:8761`?

Comment: It already has `NodePort` service by default  in `values.yaml` it should be accessible from `nodeIp:8761`.

Comment: I tried but it's not

Comment: Check port `http://....:30066`

Comment: no, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the provider that you have, if it support service type Load Balancers you should change your values.yaml to

```yaml
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 8761
```

Then your Eureka Server should be available at `http://....:8761`

---

Based on what you have in [service.yaml](https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart/templates/service.yaml) and [values.yaml](https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart/values.yaml#L30) your Eureka Server should be available at **http://....:30066** as you are using `NodePort`

Comment: I use native kubernetes installed on Debian. It's not a AWS cluster.

Comment: When you have native kubernetes so easier is to use `NodePort`. `LoadBalancer` is hard to use this way, if you it you will have to read about `MetalLB`. Personally I never had a chance to used it